# Malware-like site opening from within Facebook

Tags: malware, mobile, virus

When I visit a link to an external site (like Huffpost) from within Facebook, I get redirected to a scammer site after scrolling a little bit.

[image]

[image]

Notice the URLs `eu.unitize370vu.pw` and `eu.jargonize22bt.pw`.

I am confident not having a virus on my phone, I don't install every app and nothing from unknown sources. What is this and where is it coming from?

I am using the latest and up to date Android.

Comment: Try installing a free mobile AV scanner, such as Sophos', just to check. Google Play tries, but it itsn't perfect at removing potentially unwanted apps (such as spam apps)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to believe that if your phone is infected, they'd need to show you ads. They can do far worse things. :)

If you're using FB in a browser, it could be one of two things:

1. It could be AdTech going bad (i.e., some advertising network
   injecting ads).
2. ISPs are known to intercept traffic to inject ads
   too.

I would try a different browser. I recommend FireFox Focus (a fairly new browser) as a remedy for such Ad nuisance.

Comment: I am using the Facebook App and when opening a link there, the redirect happens after scrolling. I am not using Facebook with the browser.

Comment: My bad, I should've been clearer. If accessing from browser, you don't even need to click any links, they can just inject while you're using FB. 
But you did say "visit a link to an external site" first. So yes, even from within the FB app, if you click on links the ISP can inject ads - because the link would open in a browser (even if it is in-app browser).
It is possible that they're using some algorithms to decide when to inject ads (e.g., after scrolling). Can't be sure without experimenting a bit (different browser, different ISP, ad-blockers, etc.). I can't think of any other reasons.

Comment: I understand. I think the chance of having a virus is about 10% but Ads with malware is about 90%. I do you see anything else causing these phishing sites to appear?

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly pointed out, this is indeed a scammer site, and has nothing to do with malware (malicious applications). 
Apps on the [Google Play Store are reviewed](https://www.theverge.com/2015/3/17/8231125/android-apps-now-reviewed-by-google) by teams of specialists, so theoretically you cannot get malware from there. To make sure that no ¨unreviewed¨ app is downloaded, [disable developer options](http://www.howtodroid.com/2013/08/how-to-enable-and-disable-developer-options-in-android.html) (if you have them enabled).

Below is the evidence that leads me to belive that both sites are illegitimate.

I ran a whois on unitize370vu.pw, and the site was registered today:

```
Domain Name: UNITIZE370VU.PW
Registry Domain ID: D50760466-CNIC
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com
Registrar URL:
Updated Date: 2017-08-02T08:21:12.0Z
Creation Date: 2017-08-02T08:21:11.0Z
```

As for the other site, it was only slightly older.

```
Domain Name: JARGONIZE22BT.PW
Registry Domain ID: D50651876-CNIC
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com
Registrar URL:
Updated Date: 2017-07-28T10:28:00.0Z
Creation Date: 2017-07-28T10:28:00.0Z
```

Both sites are resisted to one ¨James Carter¨, who works for ¨Friendly Advice¨.

In case you cannot read German, the text reads the following (I ran an online OCR in German to get the text, then passed it to google translate):

```
The page on 'eu.unitize370vu.pw' says:
Congratulations!

Google users! They were selected as winners of today's FREE iPhone 7, PlayStation 4 or Samsung Galaxy's S6!

Please click OK to claim your price before we give it to someone else!

You only have 1 minute and 30 seconds to answer the 3 following questions before the prizes are awarded to another happy visitor! Good luck!
```

**While being on this site will not harm any device**, it can track your IP address, which can be used to find your information, including your ISP, (full) name and even address. To avoid this happening to you, never click on a link on Facebook, but rather search the title on Google and verify that the URL is a legitimate one, like www.huffingtonpost.com.

Comment: Can you remove this line, please? `"Apps on the Google Play Store are reviewed by teams of specialists, so theoretically you cannot get malware from there. "` [Here's why](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+play+malware).

Comment: Also, what do you mean, `"While being on this site will not harm any device"`? How can you tell? Did you check for browser hooks such as BeEF, etc? I'm downvoting you until the content of this post improves.